is there a list of actions on Wordpress
Often, I see a lot of useful functions under "add_action" for example "plugins_loaded",  "admin_init", "show_user_profile", etc.
Is there a website or similar which had a list of all of them? or any chance to get them of the Wordpress itself?
Thanks a lot.

do you mean the official developer docs/code reference?

There's the two lists at the bottom of this page. That's about it for first-party documentation. Another handy resource is Adam Brown's WordPress Hooks Database, but that seems to be a little out of date.
